# Middleware execute after __construct in laravel5.3?

Tags: laravel

As far as I know , when we set a middlere in laravel route,  the application may filter before execute the controller.

For example , In laravel5.2
route.php

```
Route::group([ 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('admin.home');
});
```

App\Http\Controllers\Controller.php

```
public function __construct()
{
        var_dump(222);
}
```

App\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
public function index()
{
    return view('welcome');
}
```

auth middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
        var_dump(111);
    return $next($request);
}
```

When I visit the website, The result is  111    222.

But in laravel 5.3  , The result is 222 111 .

Why? Any help is appreciated! o(∩_∩)o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find it in laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/middleware-execute-after-construct-in-laravel53